# Custom validation not firing in formview control

Tags: asp.net

Hello I am having trouble figuring out where the issue is with a custom validation control. The background is that I have a formview control within the EditTemplate of the formview, I have a date field. I want to validate if the date is in the past. If it is then cause error message and basically don't update. Thanks for Guidance.

**Date field is TxtProjectPlannedEndDate**

```
    <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtProjectPlannedEndDate" runat="server" class="form- 
    control" Text='<%# Eval("Planned Completion Date", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")%>' 
    />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorPlannedEndDate" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Planned End date can't be in the past" 
    ClientValidationFunction="ValidatePastDates" CssClass="text-danger" 
    ControlToValidate="TxtProjectPlannedEndDate" Display="Dynamic"> 
    </asp:CustomValidator>
    </td>
```

**Buttons in EditTemplate of the FormView**

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" CommandName="Update" runat="server" 
    ToolTip="Save Modifications" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Save" 
    CausesValidation="true" />
    <asp:LinkButton 
    ID="CancelButton" CommandName="Cancel" runat="server" ToolTip="Cancel" 
    CssClass="btn btn-warning" Text="Abort" CausesValidation="false" />
```

**My Script**

```
function ValidatePastDates(source, args) {

debugger;
var selectedDate = parseDate(document.getElementById('MainContent_FrmVwProjectDetails_TxtProjectPlannedEndDate').value);
var projectStatus = document.getElementById('MainContent_FrmVwProjectDetails_ddlStatus');
var projectStatusValue = projectStatus.options[projectStatus.selectedIndex].value;
var userRole = document.getElementById('MainContent_hdnUserRole').value;

var now = new Date();
var dt1 = Date.parse(now);
dt2 = Date.parse(selectedDate);
debugger;

if (userRole.indexOf("Basic User") >= 0 || userRole.indexOf("Project Manager") >= 0)
    // if user is basic user or project manager only the validate for past dates
    // Administrator or manager roles can have dates in the past for the purpose of corrections that might need to happen
{
    if (dt2 < dt1) {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
    else {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
}

}

function parseDate(s) {
var months = {
    jan: 0, feb: 1, mar: 2, apr: 3, may: 4, jun: 5,
    jul: 6, aug: 7, sep: 8, oct: 9, nov: 10, dec: 11
};
var p = s.split('-');
return new Date(p[2], months[p[1].toLowerCase()], p[0]);
debugger;
}
```

Comment: so what is currently happening. are you getting any errors??

Comment: No errors .. it just goes out of the edit mode. Looks like it just doesn't call the script.